# Syntax error from Doctrine generated query for getting one particular property

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony 4 and Doctrine 2. I came into this problem that Doctrine generated a bad query for me.

I have two entities, CharacterModel and Character. Each character model can only be one character, and each character can have a lot of character models. So I draw their relationship like this in the entities. All the getters and setter were set.

CharacterModel.php

```
class CharacterModel
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var Character 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Character", inversedBy="characterModels")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="character_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $character;
```

Character.php

```
class Character
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**         
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=30, nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var CharacterModel
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CharacterModel", mappedBy="character")
     */
    protected $characterModels;
```

controller.php

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$characterModel = $em->getRepository(CharacterModel::class)->find($id);

// get character used by id
echo $characterModel->getCharacter()->getId();
```

The above getId call will work, but when I try to getName, it gave me a syntax error on the generated query.

```
// this doesn't work
echo $characterModel->getCharacter()->getName();

// Error message
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name AS name_2 FROM character t0 WHERE t0.id = ?' with params [1]:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'character t0 WHERE t0.id = 1' at line 1
```

I did some tests on other getters from other entities, they all works except this particular one. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error probably occurs because `character` is a SQL reserved word.

In that case, you have to specify and quote the table name in Doctrine mapping (or change Entity name)

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`character`")
 */
class Character
{
```